# Form validation doesn't work in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have login form which take username and password as user inputs and when I implement CodeIgniter form validator it doesn't pass the validation. I have included my form and validation controller.

login.php view file snippet.

```
<div class="tab-content">

                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="user">
                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>

                    <br>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="right-inner-addon">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <input
                                        class="form-control input-lg" type="text"
                                        placeholder="Username" id="username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="right-inner-addon">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> <input
                                        class="form-control input-lg" type="password"
                                        placeholder="Password" id="passowrd">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>
                        <div class=" text-center">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT" />

                        </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
```

And this is validatelogin.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('home', 'refresh');
   }

 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
?>
```

I have referenced form validator documentation, but couldn't find any problem with my code.

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/09/create-login-and-registration-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

Your input field has `name` missing in both fields. Add `name="username"` `name="password"` in fields.

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="right-inner-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> 
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="right-inner-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> 
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passowrd" name="passowrd">
        </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put name on username and password input:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username">

<input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passowrd" name="password">
```